# Running a client/server through a fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to connect my java server to an android client (which I've achieved for one simple activity). Now I want to add a list/details fragment and be able to pass information to and from the server and back to the list and details. I'm using this example as my list/details view fragment:

[Android fragments example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

I have 3 questions:

- Is it possible to then run the server from that fragment and pass information to and from the server?
- Would I only have the connection start in the main activity or all of the fragments?
- If only in the main activity, how would I pass information back fourth from the fragments to the main activity?

I am quite new to android and still learning which is why I ask all the strange questions.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) You cannot run the server communication on the fragment. What I mean is, it has to run on a different thread than on UI thread. The fragment itself runs on the UI thread.

You can technically write the "server" code on the same class as the fragment as long as it runs on a different thread but also know this - fragments have lifecycles which means that once the user moves to another fragment/activity or goes back to the launcher - the server and communication will be killed!

You should create an Android service that does that communication stuff and keeps running in the background even when your application is hidden/not running (as you see fit).

2) You only start the connection once, no need to start it from every fragment/activity.

3) There are lots of ways for passing around data. This usually happens with intents, read about it.

Implementation may differ, but the important thing is to remember not to run long duration tasks on the main thread since it will make your application freeze and hence it will be killed by Android.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! What I have been doing up until now is stopping the server with every intent launch and starting it when the next activity is fired. Would an Asynctask be sufficient instead of an android service? I'm just concerned where I could read the string I would return from my server. In onPostExecute?

Comment: It's very hard to know what is the best solution for your app.
AsyncTask is good if the network communication is a short one-timer, like connecting to a server, downloading an image, and when the answer arrives from server, update the UI and be done with it. AsyncTask is just an easy way execute on a new Thread and then be able to communicate results back to the UI but it is not suitable for long running tasks. Its good for tasks that live around few seconds long.

For a long, continuous communication a service is the answer.

Comment: Btw if my answer helped you question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Do you possibly have a good link I could reference as this is the first time I'm hearing of an Android service?

Comment: This is a good read, good luck!

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html